# Specify Reduced Redundancy storage for amazon s3 objects uploaded using Fine Uploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

Where would I specify that I want the uploaded objects to Amazon S3 via Fine Uploader, to use Reduced Redundancy?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the ability to use reduced redundancy storage for Fine Uploader S3 will be part of the 4.0 release.  A new boolean property (`reducedRedundancy`) will be added to the `objectProperties` option.  This work is already completed in the develop branch in the Github repo.  You can read more about this and see the commit(s) by looking at [feature #1008](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1008).

Comment: as Ray noted, objectProperties.reducedRedundancy (see http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#objectproperties-option)